# Rails parameters not being passed to create a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

Hello guys I am working on a login page with a javascript/html/css frontend and a rails backend. So when clicking on a signup button in my front end I am making a POST request to the create action in rails and passing a username, password and password confirmation. I put a byebug in the create action to look at the params and it looks like this

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"username"=>"ray",
 "password"=>"1234",
 "password_confirmation"=>"1234",
 "controller"=>"users",
 "action"=>"create",
 "user"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"username"=>"ray"} permitted: false>} permitted: false>
```

I try to save the user but for some reason I can't save the user because the password and password_confirmation are not being returned from my user_params method. This is what my UsersController looks like.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      render json: {
        status: 200,
        user: user
      }
    else
      render json: {
        status: 401,
        message: "Failure!"
      }
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      byebug
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation)      
    end
end
```

I guess what I don't understand is why only the username is being plugged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your incoming parameters look like this:

```
{
  "username" => "ray",
  "password" => "1234",
  "password_confirmation" => "1234",
  "user" => { "username" => "ray" }
}
```

but the `require` in your `user_params`:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation)
```

is looking at the `user` in those parameters and then the `permit` looks for the `username`, `password`, ... within `user`. So `user_params` is looking for input like this:

```
{
  "user" => {
    "username" => "ray",
    "password" => "1234",
    "password_confirmation" => "1234"
  }
}
```

So either fix your front end to send the data properly nested with `"user"` as above or fix `user_params` to look for everything at the top level:

```
params.permit(:username, :password, :password_confirmation)
```

Comment: You were right! I decided to go with fixing my front end. I nested everything under user and it is now working properly. Thanks so much! Enjoy your holiday!